# How to Prepare a Blend Object .svg for Processing?

Tags: image-processing, svg, processing, adobe-illustrator, generative-art

I'm struggling to prepare a correct .svg file of a blend object to load it in Processing the way it looks in Illustrator. I figured out that I can export compound paths successfully so I tried to turn a blend object to a compound path, but can't find a way of doing so. What is the right way of preparing blend object .svg for Processing? I want to have shapes like this:
[image]